# Why isn't $RANDOM included in the output of 'env'?

Tags: shell, environment-variables

I know `env` is a shell command, it can be used to print a list of the current environment variables. And as far as I understand, `RANDOM` is also
a environment variable.

So why, when I launch `env` on Linux, does the output not include `RANDOM`?

Comment: `env` is not a shell command since it is usually not built into the shell.

Comment: @schily BTW for Bash, `declare -x` is the equivalent in a shell builtin.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`RANDOM` is not an environment variable. It's a shell variable maintained by some shells.  It is generally not exported by default.  This is why it doesn't show up in the output of `env`.

Once it's been used at least once, it *would* show up in the  output of `set`, which, by itself, lists the shell variables (and functions) and their values in the current shell session.  This behaviour is dependent on the shell and using `pdksh` on OpenBSD, `RANDOM` would be listed by `set` even if not previously used.

---

The rest of this answer concerns what could be expected to happen if `RANDOM` was exported (i.e. turned into an environment variable).

Exporting it with `export RANDOM` would make it an environment variable but its use would be severely limited as its value in a child process would be "random but static" (meaning it would be an unchanging random number). The exact behaviour differs between shells.

I'm using `pdksh` on OpenBSD in the example below and I get a new random value in each `awk` run (but the *same* value every time within the same `awk` instance).  Using `bash`, I would get exactly the same random value in *all* invocations of `awk`.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { print ENVIRON["RANDOM"], ENVIRON["RANDOM"] }'
25444 25444

$ awk 'BEGIN { print ENVIRON["RANDOM"], ENVIRON["RANDOM"] }'
30906 30906
```

In `bash`, the exported value of `RANDOM` would remain static regardless of the use of `RANDOM` in the shell (where each use of `$RANDOM` would still give a new value).

This is because each reference to the *shell variable* `RANDOM` in `bash` makes the shell access its internal `get_random()` function to give the variable a new random value, but the shell does not update the *environment variable* `RANDOM`.  This is similar in behaviour as with other dynamic `bash` variables, such as `LINENO`, `SECONDS`, `BASHPID` etc.

To update the environment variable `RANDOM` in `bash`, you would have to assign it the value of the shell variable `RANDOM` *and* re-export it:

```
export RANDOM="$RANDOM"
```

It is unclear to me if this would have the additional side effect of re-seeding the random number generator in `bash` or not (but an educated guess would be that it doesn't).

Comment: Does `RANDOM` even have a value before you use it? I had always assumed it was only populated when called.

Comment: @terdon - that's my understanding as well, it has no value until called.

Comment: @terdon Good question! I will look at the sources in a few moments.

Comment: It isn't, the bash manual mentions it.

Comment: `ksh93` re-randomizes every time I run `set | grep RANDOM`, or something like `env` or that `awk`; zsh and Bash don't, and Bash doesn't even show it in `set` (or `declare`) before it's otherwise used.

Comment: Though if you do even `export RANDOM` or `declare -p RANDOM`, it appears, so I'm not sure if it's any use that it doesn't exist before being referenced...

Comment: @ilkkachu - that's interesting that it doesn't show up in `set` output until used. From there on it's static.

Comment: I was just going to comment on the exported value being static. That's really weird though: all of `set`, `export` and `declare` show the in-shell value and there doesn't seem to be a way to see the value that's actually going to be exported without actually running an external command...

Comment: $RANDOM is shell variable from ksh88 if bash did implement it like ksh, then the actual value would be exported.

Comment: @ilkkachu: as in your answer you mean `declare -x` = `export`, not `-p`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, no, I mean `declare -p`. It'll print the variable definition, which at least on my Bash is enough to make it get a value and appear in `set`. For normal unset variables, it prints an error. Repeatedly running `declare -p RANDOM` also generates new values.

Comment: "Its value in a child process would be random, but static." [If it is static, it is not random](https://www.xkcd.com/221/), whether it's three bytes or sixteen.

Comment: @l0b0 It would be random in the sense that you wouldn't be able to predict it. Obviously, once you've read it, it's not random any longer since it won't change (unless re-exporting as I showed, in which case the environment variable would get a new random value). This is why I said it's random but static. I've clarified this in the text somewhat now.

Comment: Obligatory xkcd for "random but static": https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: All you need to do to refresh the value of the `RANDOM` environment variable in bash is to re-export it: `export RANDOM; env | grep 'RANDOM='; export RANDOM; env | grep 'RANDOM='`.

Comment: @G-Man Using `bash` 4.4.23 on OpenBSD, it is _not_ enough to just re-export `RANDOM`.

Comment: @l0b0 What does "random value" mean, if not "value selected via a randomization process?"

Comment: @8bittree That's the point of the XKCD - a *given value* can never be random. Only a generator can be. But the "why" of that is probably better as a math.SE question.

Comment: @l0b0 My point is that the term "random value" is shorthand for "value selected via a randomization process." Therefore, a variable with a "random, but static" value would be a variable whose initial value was set by a randomization process and whose value does not subsequently change over time. Random and static are not mutually exclusive here.

Answer (score 17):

Not all variables that are set in your shell session are environment variables. "Environment variables" refers only to those variables that have been exported to the environment using the `export` builtin. The `env` command only prints such *environment* variables. For example:

```
$ foo="bar"
$ env | grep foo ## returns nothing
$ export foo
$ env | grep foo ## now, env will print it
foo=bar
```

If you want to see all variables set in your session, irrespective of whether they have been exported, you can use `set`:

```
$ set | grep foo=
foo=bar
```

The `set` builtin also returns functions, so to see variables only, you can use:

```
set | grep  '^[^[:space:]]*='
```

Finally, the `RANDOM` variable is special in that it is only assigned a value when you reference it. This is mentioned in [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html):

> **`RANDOM`**
>
>   Each time this parameter is referenced, a random integer 
>     between  0  and
>               32767 is generated.  The sequence of random numbers may be initialized by
>               assigning a value to
>   **`RANDOM`**
>   .  If
>   **`RANDOM`**
>   is unset, it  loses  its  special
>               properties, even if it is subsequently reset.

So even if it were an environment variable as you thought, it wouldn't have been shown in `env` since it wouldn't be set until the first time you called it. That is also why it isn't shown in `set`:

```
$ set | grep RAN   ## returns nothing, RANDOM is unset
$ echo "$RANDOM"   ## this will assign a value to RANDOM
1234
$ set | grep RAN   ## so now it will also appear in the output of set 
RANDOM=1234
```

Comment: That’s an interesting discovery, regarding `set | grep RAN`.  I wouldn’t have expected it.  FWIW, I believe that it can’t be predicted by the documentation.

Comment: P.S. Congratulations on reaching 120,000. (I guess I just put you over.)

Answer (score 5):

Most shells will have a number of other variables set or used by the shell that aren't exported to child processes by default.

In Bash, there are some obviously Bash-specific ones:

```
$ echo "${!BASH*}"
BASH BASHOPTS BASHPID BASH_ALIASES BASH_ARGC BASH_ARGV BASH_CMDS BASH_COMMAND BASH_LINENO BASH_SOURCE BASH_SUBSHELL BASH_VERSINFO BASH_VERSION
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.4.12(1)-release
$ env|grep -c BASH
0
```

Then there's more standard ones like `OPTIND` and `OPTERR` (used by `getopts`), and `PS2`, `PS3` (the secondary prompts) and even another "magic" variable: `SECONDS` (shows the time in seconds since the shell started)

In Bash, you can see all the variables and their export status with `declare -p`. The ones marked with `-x` are exported, the ones without `x` aren't. (Some will have other flags like `i` for integer or `r` for read-only.)

In Zsh or ksh93, you can use `typeset -p`, though Zsh marks the exported variables by changing `typeset` to `export` in the output, instead of using flags. `export` by itself would also show all the exported variables, but that's about the same result you get by running `env`.

Answer (score 3):

If you google for this, the docs state the following:

> `$RANDOM` is an internal Bash [function](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html#FUNCTIONREF) (not a constant) that returns a pseudorandom [[1]](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html#FTN.AEN5817) integer in the range 0 - 32767. It should not be used to generate an encryption key.

If you use `strace` you can see that the `$RANDOM` "variable" is passed in directly to commands as if it were any ordinary shell variable or an environment variable, but it's just a internal function that's built into the shell, Bash, that's doing the expansion.

```
$ strace -t echo "random value: $RANDOM"
04:37:58 execve("/bin/echo", ["echo", "random value: 30795"], [/* 27 vars */]) = 0
04:37:58 brk(NULL)                      = 0x19c1000
04:37:58 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9841351000
...
```

vs. this regular variable:

```
$ strace -t echo "random value: $SOMEVAR"
04:40:19 execve("/bin/echo", ["echo", "random value: helloworld"], [/* 27 vars */]) = 0
04:40:19 brk(NULL)                      = 0x154b000
04:40:19 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f659d2eb000
...
```

The variable is not being passed on as a reference.

#### References

- [$RANDOM: generate random integer](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html)

Comment: well, isn't that passing the expanded value of `$RANDOM` or `$SOMEVAR` through a command line argument, and not as an environment variable? You'd need to `export` both to pass them through the environment.

Comment: No that would make no difference. The shell expands them regardless. The way I showed it is basically highlighting the fact that the shell is doing the expansion.

Comment: The `strace` output doesn't seem to catch the internal function run by the shell. In both cases, the variable has already been expanded in the first line of the `strace`. I don't understand what difference you are pointing to. What am I missing?

Comment: Showing that the `$RANDOM` expansion is done internally to the shell. It's basically confirmation that the shell is determining the value, and not passing a reference to a variable. The shell when it's expanding the command line to execute parses `$RANDOM` and passes the expanded form to `echo`.

Comment: So, nothing like an *environment* variable, then.